# How to use SetActive()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a registration scene. I want to show three panels when the user enters an invalid name, email, and/or password. I have the panels hidden at start. That works. However, the panels don't show up when I enter invalid info and click the button. When `validName`, `validEmail`, and `validPassword` are false, it goes into ShowNamePanel() and gets stuck.

What's wrong with my code?

```
public GameObject namePanel;
public GameObject emailPanel;
public GameObject passwordPanel;

public void Start ()
{
    HideNamePanel ();
    HideEmailPanel ();
    HidePasswordPanel ();
}

public void ButtonClick ()
{
    Debug.Log ("1. Button clicked.");

    CreateUser ();
}

/*
 * Sends post request to create new user if name, email, and 
 * password are valid.
 */

public void CreateUser ()
{

    validName = IsValidName (username);
    validEmail = IsValidEmailAddress (email);
    validPW = IsValidPassword (password);
    //validNewUserCombo = IsValidNewUserCombo (email, password);

    if (validName && validEmail && validPW) {
        Debug.Log ("6. VALID INPUTS");
        CallAPI ();
    } else {
        Debug.Log ("8. INVALID INPUTS");
        if (validName == false) {
            ShowNamePanel ();
        }
        if (validEmail == false) {
            ShowEmailPanel ();
        }
        if (validPW == false) {
            ShowPasswordPanel ();
        }
    }
}

public void ShowNamePanel() {
    Debug.Log ("shownamepanel");
    namePanel.SetActive (true);
}

public void HideNamePanel() {
    namePanel.SetActive (false);
}

public void ShowEmailPanel() {
    Debug.Log ("showemailpanel");
    emailPanel.SetActive (true);
}

public void HideEmailPanel() {
    emailPanel.SetActive (false);
}

public void ShowPasswordPanel() {
    Debug.Log ("showpasswordpanel");
    passwordPanel.SetActive (true);
}

public void HidePasswordPanel() {
    passwordPanel.SetActive (false);
}
```

[Connecting variables in the Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4reY.png)

[Panel hirearchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YalyD.png)

Comment: Did you intend to have your calls to passwordPanel.SetActive (true) and other SetActive(true) calls commented out?

Comment: What do you mean by it gets stuck, does it crash?

Comment: @JHH Yes, I was testing to make sure it enters the other Show methods. When I un-comment those lines, it gets stuck in `namePanel.SetActive (true);` and doesn't ever go into the other methods.

Comment: @CNuts No, it doesn't crash. When name, email, and password are false, it's supposed to go in all three Show methods. However, it goes into `ShowNamePanel()`, gets to the `namePanel.SetActive (true);` and then doesn't progress after that.

Comment: Can you try moving your namePanel.SetActive(true); inside the if and not use it in a method.

Comment: @CNuts I just tried that and am getting the same result.

Comment: Okay how are you getting access to the panels?

Comment: @CNuts I added image links at the bottom of the OP with how I've connected the panels to the variables...did I do it right? namePanel, etc are of type GameObject.

Comment: Is this script attached to one of those panels?

Comment: @CNuts Yes, this script is attached to all three panels.

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so your problem is that when a game object is inactive all script that this game object has stop working too. So if you want this to work you're better off putting the script on something else that will stay active during the process.

In your case the moment you setActive(false) the panels, the script on them are inactive too so they won't run anymore.

This is from the [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html) :

> Making a GameObject inactive will disable every component, turning off any attached renderers, colliders, rigidbodies, scripts, etc...

Comment: Thanks. So I created one script called `HidePanelCtrl` with methods `HideNamePanel()`, `HideEmailPanel()`, and `HidePasswordPanel()` and attached them to the panels. I made second script called `ShowPanelCtrl` with methods `ShowNamePanel()`, `ShowEmailPanel()`, and `ShowPasswordPanel()` and connected it to a submit button. The submit button is also connected to the third script: `NewUser`. I use `NewUser` to call the first two scripts to hide and show the panels. Is this what you mean? Hiding panels is working but showing panels still doesn't work. :(

Comment: Ignore my last comment. I made a script called HideShowPanelCtrl with the show and hide methods. I put the script on the submit button. I also put a NewUser script on the submit button and use the NewUser script to call the methods in show and hide. Is that what you mean? I don't have any scripts on the panels anymore. Hide works but show still doesn't work.

Comment: Is your button always active during all that?

Comment: Yes, it's active. I have a Debug.Log message that prints to console every time the button is clicked. The button clicks still register after the panels become inactive.

Comment: I'm getting a NullReferenceException where I call ShowNamePanel(). It says the object reference not set to an instance of an object NewUser.CreateUser(). But I used showPanelCtrl in start() and it worked fine.

Comment: That means that you haven't assigned your panel in the inspector.

Comment: And keep everything in one script you don't need to have 2 different script on the same object for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Unity what panels you're trying to disable/enable, like this:

```
public Panel panelToToggle;
private void Awake()
{
     // Gets the Panel component if there's one on the GameObject this
     // script is attached to
     panelToToggle = GetComponent<Panel>();
}
private void Start()
{
     // Sets the parent gameObject of the Panel component to inactive
     panelToToggle.gameObject.SetActive(false)
}
private void EnablePanel()
{
     // Sets the parent gameObject of the Panel component to active
     panelToToggle.gameObject.SetActive(true)
}
```

Comment: What namespace do I use to get `Panel` to work? I get an error when I type `public Panel namePanel`. I've got `using System.Collections;`,
`using System.Collections.Generic;`,
`using UnityEngine;`,
`using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;`,
`using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`,
`using System;`,
`using UnityEngine.UI;`, and 
`using UnityEngine.EventSystems;` already. Also - I've got namePanel, emailPanel, and and passwordPanel connected to their respective panels in the Inspector. Is that different than using GetComponent?

Comment: Sorry Panel was just a placeholder class. That would be whatever the class of the component you want to reference is - so if it's an InputField, it would be InputField, if it was a Canvas it would be Canvas, if it was a custom script it would be that script's class, and so on.
  

If you have them assigned in the inspector it should work the same. Just make sure the GameObject they're attached to is active at the start of the scene. Let the Awake or Start methods disable things, otherwise Unity can't reference them.